# Powershell Regex Log entry as string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get information from this line of text:

```
C:\Tmp\TmsNcc-200602_000002_Log_cab.txt:3052:00:19:33.754 ( 5200: 9244) G-MST: 2000007C " guid=00030001-69f7-5c7f-227e-00104941c969" ("10.12.12.102","10.12.12.115"),(0, 0),2(ULaw),rsn:1,04:19:28.505 (UTC),pl:20,(s:257, 
r:263, l:0),(j:0,u:0,o:0) flgs:0x00000000 "sip:8203@10.12.12.2:5661",vpn:0
```

I am trying to get the GUID, J:#, U:#, o:#, and the two IP addresses, and finally the sip information at the end.

Working on it This is what I have so far:

```
$Test = $UnderRun.tostring()
$Tmp = (($Test -replace "^['guid'\= ]","").Split('"'))
$GUID = (($Test -replace "^['guid'\= ]","").Split('"'))[1] -replace ' guid=',''
$Stats = (($Test.Split('(,)')[22]).split(',')) -replace ".:",""
$Sip = $Test.Split("""")[7]
$VPN = if ($Test.Split("""")[8] -replace ',vpn:','' -eq '0') {$false} else {$true}
$Year = "20$(($Test.Split('-_')[1]).substring(0,2))"
$Month = ($Test.Split('-_')[1]).substring(2,2)
$Day = ($Test.Split('-_')[1]).substring(4,2)
$Date = "$Day/$Month/$year"
$Time = "$($Test.Split('-_')[4].split(":")[3]):$($Test.Split('-_')[4].split(":")[4] -replace "4 .*",'')"
$FromIP = $Tmp[3]
$ToIP = $Tmp[5]
$Jitter = $Stats[0]
$Unders = $Stats[1]
$Overs = $Stats[2]
$Return += [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    Date = $Date
    Time = $Time
    Guid = $GUID
    Sip = $Sip
    VPN = $VPN
    From = $FromIP
    To = $ToIP
    Jitter = $Jitter
    UnderRuns = $UnderRuns
    OverRuns = $Overs
}
```

Comment: Please share code you have so far…

Comment: Adding my work as I go along.

Comment: There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data format is predictable and always in the order as shown above, you can use the `-match` operator against single strings. Then return matched values from the `$matches` automatic variable:

```
$string = 'C:\Tmp\TmsNcc-200602_000002_Log_cab.txt:3052:00:19:33.754 ( 5200: 9244) G-MST: 2000007C " guid=00030001-69f7-5c7f-227e-00104941c969" ("10.12.12.102","10.12.12.115"),(0, 0),2(ULaw),rsn:1,04:19:28.505 (UTC),pl:20,(s:257, r:263, l:0),(j:0,u:0,o:0) flgs:0x00000000 "sip:8203@10.12.12.2:5661",vpn:0'
$regex = 'guid=(?<guid>[-a-f\d]+).*?\("(?<IP1>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})","(?<IP2>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})"\).*?\br:(?<r>\d+).*?\bj:(?<j>\d+).*?\bu:(?<u>\d+).*?\bsip:(?<sip>[^"]+)'
$null = $string -match $regex
[pscustomobject]@{
    Guid = $matches.guid
    Jitter = $matches.j
    IP1 = $matches.IP1
    IP2 = $matches.IP2
    Underruns = $matches.u
    SIP = $matches.sip
    R = $matches.r
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `-match` operator uses regex to perform string matching. When the left-hand side (LHS) of `-match` is a single string, the operator will return `True` if the match is successful and `False` otherwise. If the return is `True`, `$matches` then contains the matched strings.

Using the syntax `()` or `(?<name>)`, capture groups are created. `name` is the capture group name when that syntax (`(?<name>)`) is used. Then `$matches.name` can be used to retrieve the matched string.

The RHS of `-match` is regex syntax. I've created an [online regex](https://regex101.com/r/ymzPJ3/1) that details how the regex mechanisms work.

Comment: From the site, I figured out how to capture the VPN information and the RSN information, but I still can't figure out how to capture the 200602. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out: '(?<date>\d+).*?\bguid=(?<guid>[-a-f\d]+).*?\("(?<IP1>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})","(?<IP2>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})"\).*?\brsn:(?<time>[^ ]+).*?\br:(?<r>\d+).*?\bj:(?<j>\d+).*?\bu:(?<u>\d+).*?\bo:(?<over>\d+).*?\bsip:(?<sip>[^"]+).*?\bvpn:(?<vpn>\d+).*?\b'